# Why `r(sqrt(x*x + y*y))` rather than `r(x)`

Tags: c++, constructor, complex-numbers

I have just started (sort of) understanding the concept of constructors, in one the exercises I have been given, I am asked to define a class `Complex` with members `r`and `phi`.

My understanding of constructors: they simply initialize the members to a predetermined value, such that if I were to include an object of type `Complex`in the main function without assigning a value to say member `phi`, the constructor would simply assign it a value that I would have set in the constructor. Following my own definition of constructors, I get confused by the fact that, in the solutions, it states:

```
class Complex {
private:
double r,phi;
public:
 Complex(double Re=0, double Im=0):
 r(sqrt(Re*Re+Im*Im)), phi(atan2(Im,Re)) {}
```

I am confused why the constructor is set to:

`Complex(double Re=0, double Im=0):
 r(sqrt(Re*Re+Im*Im)), phi(atan2(Im,Re)) {}`

Since the constructor's purpose is simply to set "missing" members of objects mentioned in the main function to a predetermined value, surely `r(sqrt(Re*Re+Im*Im))` and `phi(atan2(Im,Re))`are excessive, and all that is needed is `r(Re)`and `phi(Im)`because it would still set `r`and `phi`equal to `0`.

I assume that I am wrong and a constructor actually does more than set "missing" members of objects mentioned in the main function to a predetermined value. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since the constructor's purpose is simply to set "missing" members - no it is not, constructor puprose to initialize all data members, missing or not.

Comment: `sqrt(a*a)` is not always the same as `a`. What if `a` is -1, for example?

Comment: `sqrt(a*a+b*b)` can't possible be equivalent to `sqrt(a)` since, first off, it is no longer a function of `b`... You seem to assume `b == 0` and `a >= 0` which is a huge assumption.

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with C++, it's just your `Complex` class is designed to store coordinates in the polar format (radius, angle), but still being able to construct from the values in Cartesian format (real, imaginary). The expressions in the Initializer list perform the conversion. See also: [Complex_number#Cartesian_complex_plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Cartesian_complex_plane) and [Complex_number#Polar_complex_plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Polar_complex_plane)

Comment: The purpose of a constructor is to **construct** an object in a known state. In this case, objects of type `Complex` hold a radius and an angle, which is one of the common representations of complex numbers. That constructor initializes the radius (`r`) and the angle (`phi`) from the values of `x` and `y` that are passed to the constructor. Apparently `x` and `y` are **rectangular** coordinates, which is another common way of representing complex numbers. So the constructor converts rectangular coordinates to polar.

Comment: You could provide a `Complex(): r{0.0}, phi{0.0} {}` as an optimization for the default case.  You'd have to remove the one-or-both of the default values on the current constructor.  Not sure how big of a performance "win" that'd be... you'd have to do some profiling.  `Complex(double Re)` would be a skosh trickier, as mentioned above about `sqrt(Re*Re)` and `atan2(0, Re)` are sign sensitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> surely `r(sqrt(Re*Re+Im*Im))` and `phi(atan2(Im,Re))` are excessive, and all that is needed is `r(Re)` and `phi(Im)` because it would still set `r` and `phi` equal to `0`.

That is an incorrect conclusion.

Given the declaration of the constructor, you can construct objects of the class by using:

```
Complex c1;             // Equivalent to Complex c1(0, 0);
Complex c2(1.0);        // Equivalent to Complex c2(1.0, 0);
Complex c3(1.0, 1.0);
```

For the first two cases, using `r(Re)` and `phi(Im)` is ok but only due to coincidence.
For the third case, using `r(Re)` and `phi(Im)` is incorrect. `r` and `phi` will be initialized to wrong values.

Using `r(sqrt(Re*Re+Im*Im))` and `phi(atan2(Im,Re))` works for all cases.

Comment: I was bothered by the fact that it states `(double Re = 0, double Im = 0)` and then any calculations like `sqrt(Re*Re + Im*Im)` is equal `0`. Are `double Re = 0, double Im = 0` like placeholders that only are assigned if no mention of that particular member is given in the main function?

Comment: @user9078057 Yes, those are default values that will be used if no value is given for that parameter.

Comment: @user9078057, your undersanding of what `(double Re = 0, double Im = 0)` means is incorrect. Those are default values only if a value is not specified. If a value is specified, then they will be used in the call instead of the default values.

Answer (score 3):

A constructor's purpose isn't to set "missing" members.  A constructor's purpose is to initialize an object to a logically-consistent initial state.

In your case your class is designed to store polar coordinates, but you're passing Cartesian coordinates to the constructor.  That means to initialize the object to a logically correct state, it has to do a conversion between the two.

Answer (score 0):

I think the challenge here is that there's 2 ways of representing imaginary numbers. One is with the real part and the imaginary part, essentially representing them on a plane with `x = real`, `y = imaginary`. The other is to represent them as points on a circle with radius and angle (polar coordinates). The constructor you have is computing the radius (`r`) using the pythagorean theorem a^2 + b^2 = c^2 ... or `r = sqrt(Re*Re + Im*Im)`, similarly, it's computing `phi` as the angle to that point.

Depending on the math you're doing with the points, one representation may work better than the other.